# Creating an input sheet on Excel and an event which will copy the input to a calculator on another sheet and archive it in a third sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with VBA and I have decided to use it as a fast way to automate data transfer.
I have data to input which needs to be archived and also posted to another sheet to be used for calculations. The outcome of these calculations will be sent to the same sheet as the input (likely using excel functions and not VBA).
I need an event that can trigger this data transfer when I paste new data. I have been using a command button for now but I just need a step in the right direction with ideas on what to use and develop on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.